# Logstash file input glob?

Tags: logstash, glob

I am using logstash file input with glob to read my files:

```
path => "/home/Desktop/LogstashInput/**/*.log"
```

Directory structure format:

```
LogstashInput => server-name => date => abc.log
```

This is reading all log files within every date directory ending with ".log".

Now I want to read only some particular log files within all date directories. Eg: `2014.11.05` directory has `abc.log, xyz.log............` 10 such files.  Then I want to read say only five particular files, how should the path input be ??

I read about exclude in logstash but it becomes a lot of files to be excluded as there are different type of files within different server-name directories and different dates

Answer (score 1):

The logstash agent is written in ruby, so refer to the ruby [glob rules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).  Based on your actual file names, you might be able to get one working.